# Set time in Jquery with hours and minutes, values read from variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am writing a reminder app, and I need to set dates with years, months, days, hours and minutes! All of these has to come from different input fields, and converted into a single date. Everything is working fine until I only use the years, months and days, but as soon as I try to add the hours and the minutes as well, I get an "invalid date" error in the console.

```
HMTL

      Esemény ideje (év): <input type="text" id="year">
        <br>
        Esemény ideje (hónap): <input type="text" id="month">
        <br>
        Esemény ideje (nap): <input type="text" id="day">
        <br>
        Esemény ideje (óra): <input type="text" id="hour">
        <br>
        Esemény ideje (perc): <input type="text" id="minute">

JQ

  let year=$("#year").val();
  let month=$("#month").val();
  let day=$("#day").val();
  let hours=$("#hour").val();
  let minutes=$("#minute").val();
  let time = new Date(year+","+month+","+day+","+hours+","+minutes)
  console.log(time);
```

Comment: You should try to construct the string in the ISO format, not with commas.

Comment: Could you please specify that a little bit?

Comment: If you pass as arguments instead of formatted string, does it fix the issue? let time = new Date(year,month,day,hours,minutes);

Comment: @daddygames Wow, it actually does. Thank you!

Comment: @makadi_88 an ISO formatted string would be something like: `new Date('2019-03-10T03:00:00.000Z')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have all the components of the date; there's no need to concatenate them into a string (which the fragile date-parsing algorithm would choke on anyway). Use [`Date`'s 2+-argument constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax):

```
new Date(+year, +month - 1, +day, +hours, +minutes);
```

The `+`s [convert the string values of your variables to numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()), and `month - 1` is necessary because JavaScript's month values are 0-indexed: January is 0, December is 11.

Answer (score 0):

Try this format

```
let time = new Date(month+"/"+day+"/"+year+"/"+" "+hours+":"+minutes+":00")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the seconds part. Try the following and make sure your inputs are of type Number

```
let time = new Date(year+","+month+","+day+","+hours+","+minutes+"00")
console.log(time);
```